# Jquery is not working with usercontrol

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webusercontrol

I have a button inside a usercontrol . The usercontrol is loaded (added) to a placeholder
by some event . 
The problem is a simple jquery click event for this button is not working .
What am I missing ? What should the selector look like ?

```
$('#mybutton').click(function () { alert("..."); });
```

Or I have to traverse to it ?

note: I managed to get the usercontrol codebehind executed .

Thanks a lot .

Comment: When you normally place some control under placeholder it's ID changes to `PlaceHolderID_YourConrolID` are you sure a button's ID is still `mybutton`.

Comment: Try this: `$('#<%= mybutton.ClientID %>').click(function () { alert("..."); });`

Comment: didn't work . any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('#mybutton').live("click", function () { alert("..."); });
```

Since the control #mybutton is added to the page AFTER $(document).ready() fires, there's no way jQuery can add the handler to that object. The live means, no matter when and how an element is created, it's "click" event will be bound to the function provided as the second argument.

BTW. #mybutton assumes that either the element is standard html object or an ASP control that after render retains ID and NAME as mybutton. If it's not, replace `$("#mybutton")` with `$("#<%= mybutton.ClientID %>")` or try setting ASP control's ClientIDMode to Static, or accessing the control by class name.

**EDIT:**

Going forward suggested method of appending event handlers is

```
$('#mybutton').on("click", function () { alert("..."); });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I tried everything, nothing worked until I changed a bind() to live().

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Use Bind if controls are statically declared in the HTML Markup and are never redrawn on postbacks, use Live for controls that are added dynamically, or repopulated on postbacks

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problems and found this solution: placed the link to the jquery file and an empty script tag on the page using the control like this (inside of the header tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

And then on the user control itself (no header tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your function here.
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check at client side that the id is the same as mybutton ? ASP.NET replaces the Client ID of all user controls with the attributes `runat="server"` .

You can view the source code to see the modified id.

Answer (score 0):

In aspx Page when you place the button inside the place holder. the Client ID automatically changed. So you have to use the Jquery End with selector. 
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

you use the $ sign use to find the dynamic control ID.

```
$("input[id$=mybutton]").click(function () { alert("..."); });
```

Comment: It did not work . The DOM tree is button > usercontrol > placeholder > page .

Comment: Right Click on the page and go to the view page source. then provide me the ClientID of that Button.

Comment: I can not find it . the button is inside a usercontrol .

Comment: You were right man . Your solution worked perfectly . But I had to put your function inside "jquery updatepanel function" . Because my usercontrol is inside <updatepanel> . Thanks a lot .